# What's difference between web-messaging with MessageChannel and without?

Tags: javascript, html

Using html5 I can do this:

```
document.getElementById('someIframe').contentWindow.postMessage('hi', 'someDomain');
```

Or I can use MessageChannel:

```
var mc = new MessageChannel();
document.getElementById('someIframe').contentWindow.postMessage('hi', 'someDomain',[mc.port2]);
```

What's real difference between this two ways? When I must use the first variant and when I must use the second variant?

Comment: The answer might be in this blog post; check it out: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/window-postmessage-messagechannel/

Comment: I've read it before but I don't inderstand real difference (becides using port).

Comment: I'd check browser support first. I don't see the `MessageChannel` constructor in Firefox.

Comment: I've read it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh781494(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @oblomov, Have you read my answer?

Comment: @plalx, yes, I'm reading it very carefully

Comment: @oblomov Is there something you didin't understand? Do you need more precisions on something?

Comment: @oblomov I think my answer should be accepted as it outlines clearly the main difference between both methods. Did you understand the answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I doubt I could explain it better than the following, however the important point is that once the port has been sent over, there's no origin checks that needs to occur for subsequent messages. When using `window.addEventListener('message', ...)`, you have to validate that the message source is trusted everytime you recieve a message.

> When you create a new MessageChannel object, it has two connected
>   MessagePort objects (port1 and port2). One of the ports is sent to
>   another window or frame, and messages can be sent and received without
>   repeated origin checking that is needed when using window.postMessage.
>   **Validation of the origin of a port and messages need only be done when
>   a port is sent to windows other than the one that created them**.
>   MessagePort simplifies the messaging process by sending and receiving
>   messages through two (and only those two) connected ports. Messages
>   are posted between the ports using postMessage. Since the ports will
>   only accept messages between the connected ports, **no further
>   validation is required once the connection is established**.
>   MessageChannel enables asynchronous communication between
>   IFrameElements, cross-domain windows, or same page communications.
>   *http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441303.aspx*

Comment: But even when you use `MessageChannel`, you're still listening to the `"message"` event, are you not?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, That is correct, however you are not listening for the `message` event on `window`, you are listening on the `port` and since you decide with who you share the `port` communications through the channel are secured without needing to constantly check the origin of the message.

Comment: @plax Sorry for silence. Is it possible to use window.postMessage for cross-domain windows? Do MessageChannel and window.postMessage have the same scopes of using and only their difference is for MessageChannel "messages can be sent and received without repeated origin checking that is needed when using window.postMessage"?